# Adding Static Library In Xcode 6

Tags: xcode, xcode6, static-libraries

I'm using Xcode 6.0.1 and need to add a library `libpt.a` to my C project. I cannot figure out how to properly integrate it into my project. I have already done **Link Binary With Libraries** however I still continue to get this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_pt_add_xpage", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am assuming that the above error means that the library has not been integrated correctly. I have already added the header file `pt.h` and included into my project. What am I doing wrong?

[image: what else?]